# Where can the automatic set of a proxy_variable be located?

Tags: linux

I'm logging in as root, remotely, via SSH to a computer at work. The computer has set the http_proxy variable, which I need to unset every time I log in, as the proxy server does not exist anymore. However I can't find where the variable is being set. The .bashrc for the root user is basically empty and there is nothing in the /etc/profile. So any ideas? The system is a Debian stretch distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution: put an unset in your .bashrc

Solution: Try 'grep'ing http_proxy in /etc/profile.d/ and the rest of /etc if not found. They comment it out or edit as you wish

Comment: Grepping did not work. I'm going the temporary solution. Thanks